# ModelBinder converting existing values in properties to null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a modelbinder like this:

```
public class CustomQuarantineModelBinder : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IQuarantineControl))
        {
            return new QuarantineModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class QuarantineModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext)
    {
        char[] delimeter = { '|' };

        if (modelBindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBindingContext));
        }

        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(modelBindingContext.ModelType);

        if (modelBindingContext.ModelType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IQuarantineControl)))
        {
            var qc = model as IQuarantineControl;

            if (qc != null)
            {
                var request = modelBindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
                string QuarantineControl = request.Form["QuarantineControl"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(QuarantineControl))
                {
                    string[] components = QuarantineControl.Split(delimeter);

                    qc.QuarantineClear();
                    qc.QuarantineControlID = Convert.ToInt32(components[0]);
                    qc.QuarantineState = (QuarantineState)Convert.ToInt32(components[1]);
                    for (int i = 2; i < components.Length; i++)
                    {
                        qc.QuarantineReasons.Add(components[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        modelBindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

However, other fields in the model is getting turned as null or empty. I would like to set QuarantineState, QuarantineControlId etc.. without affecting other values. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your custom `IModelBinderProvider` returns a binder, that binder is responsible for binding the entire type. If you wish to fall back to the default MVC binder for other properties, you will need to do so explicitly.

Perhaps something like;

```cs
public class CustomQuarantineModelBinder : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private readonly IModelBinderProvider baseProvider;
    public CustomQuarantineModelBinder(IModelBinderProvider baseProvider){
        this.baseProvider = baseProvider;
    }
    
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context){
        ...
        return new QuarantineModelBinder(BaseProvider.GetBinder(context));
    }
}

public class QuarantineModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IModelBinder binder;
    public QuarantineModelBinder(IModelBinder binder){
        this.binder = binder;
    }
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext)
    {
        ...
        binder.BindModelAsync(modelBindingContext);
        ...
    }
}

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var baseProvider = options.ModelBinderProviders
        .OfType<ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider>()
        .First();
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomQuarantineModelBinder(baseProvider));
});
```

Comment: thanks, this worked like a charm. i was stuck for 2 days. However, a small query how can i call my other binders like decimalbinder, intbinder etc prior to this binder provider? I did do this: options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomIntModelBinderProvider());
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(1, new CustomDateTimeModelBinderProvider());
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(2, new CustomDecimalModelBinderProvider());
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(3, new CustomQuarantineModelBinder(baseProvider));

Comment: Right, the final order of the `ModelBinderProviders` list is important, particularly as they relate to the built in providers. As the first provider to return a binder for each type is the one used.

Answer (score 0):

When the model object is posted the string values that are empty are converted to null. This is the default behavior of the MVC model binder.

You can try a workaround like this,

```
public sealed class EmptyStringModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
  {
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
     ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
      //Binders = new ModelBinderDictionary() { DefaultBinder = this };
      return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
  }
```

Comment: this isnt working for .net 6. this looks like asp.net framework code.